# VBA Excel: How to loop through Column B for cells containing alphanumeric or just numeric content?

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in column B that I need to loop through and then copy the corresponding value in column D for each row, to another sheet in the same workbook.
I need a code written to search through every value in Column B, return the corresponding value in Column D for the same row, and then find the next numbers in order from the given range(in this case I have set it from 7 to 10).

So loop through Column B, find values 7, 7a, 8, 9, 10 in that order (even if a larger value is located before a lower value as you go down), and copy the corresponding values in Column D to another sheet.
Excel Data Chart in Sheet3 (Column A is not needed):

A    B   C    D        E

```
1   1a  78.15   77.68      This is row 7
1a  2   77.18   76.92
2   3   76.92   76.63
3   4   76.13   75.78
4   4a  75.78   75.21
4a  5   75.11   74.87
5   5a  74.87   74.69
5a  6   73.94   73.6
6   6a  73.1    72.71
6a  6b  72.41   72.18
6b  10  72.18   71.6
10  11  71.3    70.89
11  12  70.89   69.83
12  13  69.83   68.68
13  14  68.68   67.68
14  15  67.63   66.46
15  16  66.01   64.84
16  16a 64.24   63.72
16a 16b 56.82   56.37
16b 16c 56.37   55.18
16c OUT 47.28   47.27
7   7a  83.12   76.07
7a  8   76.17   75.99
8   9   74.79   74.41
9   6   74.51   74        This is row 31
```

My problem: When the code encounters a cell containing letters AND numbers, it skips that cell and moves to the next cell in that range containing only numbers. How do I edit/re-write the code to INCLUDE alphanumeric values in the search criteria?

Here is my code that loops through column B but excludes cells with letters and numbers:

```
Sub EditBEST()

Dim Startval As Long
Dim Endval As Long          'Finds values corresponding
                            'to input in B and C
Dim LastRow As Long



LastRow = Sheets("Sheet3").range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Startval = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, "O").Value
Endval = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, "P").Value


StartRow = 2                                            'row that first value will be pasted in



For x = 7 To LastRow                                         'decides range to search thru in "Sheet3"

   If Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 2).Value >= 7 And Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 2).Value <= 10 Then               'if cell is not blank
        Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(StartRow, 2).Value = _
                 Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 4).Value             'copy/select cell value in D
         StartRow = StartRow + 1                                      'cell.Offset(0, 1).Value =
        End If
        If Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 3) >= 7 And Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 3).Offset(0, 1) <= 10 Then
            Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(StartRow, 2).Value = _
                Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 5).Value
        StartRow = StartRow + 1
        End If

Next x


End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: Explain what part of your code fails to do what you want / expect. Have you debugged manually by going line by line to determine where your problem is coming from? As it stands your post is basically "I want code that does x. Here's some code that does some portion of x" - there is no question there.  Also, an example block of your data would help to show what you mean by going through 7, 7a,7b, etc.

Comment: I have edited my original question. The code works without presenting an error, but it skips the cells containing a letter as well. It only copies the values in Column D corresponding to the cells that only contain numbers. I need to include the cells with letters as well in the desired range.

Comment: In short, you will need to specifically tell VBA to split out a numeric and a non-numeric string to do your comparisons. VB reads "7a" as a string only, and not a number. So something like, for each cell you go down, do a loop for each character in that cell. Check each character, 1 at a time, to see if that character is a number. Once you hit the first non-numeric character, split the text into number and letter. As to how to sort the remaining alpha character, I'm not sure. Perhaps you should create a new hypothetical range, and sort it and just go through it in order.

Comment: Sounds like a good starting point. I have been working on switching it to accommodate the string. The complex part is really the alpha character.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue you are having is that you're conditional check filters out any string values.   As @ Grade 'Eh' Bacon pointed out, you need to provide some way to handle string values.

---

You also have some comments that are wrong or misleading.

For example, here, you have added the comment "if cell is not blank" but this is not what you are actually checking.

```
If Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 2).Value >= 7 And Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 2).Value <= 10 Then               'if cell is not blank
```

If you want to check if a cell is blank, you can check it's length.  E.g.:

```
If Len(Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 2).Value) > 0 Then
```

Now, that's really not entirely necessary for this procedure, but I just wanted to point it out since your comment indicates you were trying to do something different than your code was doing.

---

I haven't tested your code, but I wrote a function for pulling a single out of a string for you.  This is all untested, so you may need to debug it, but should get your string problem sorted.

```
Sub EditBEST()

    Dim Startval As Long
    Dim Endval As Long          'Finds values corresponding
                            'to input in B and C
    Dim StartOutputRow as Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Dim Val as Long
    Dim Val2 as Long

    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet3").range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Startval = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, "O").Value
    Endval = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, "P").Value

    StartOutputRow =2      'first row we will output to
    OutputRow = StartOutputRow      'row of the cell to which matching values will be pasted

    For x = 7 To LastRow

       Val = GetSingleFromString(Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 2).Value)

       If Val >= 7 And Val <= 10 Then               'if value is within range
           Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(OutputRow , 2).Value = _
                 Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 4).Value             'copy cell  value from D @the current row to column B @the output row
           OutputRow = OutputRow + 1    'Next value will be on the next row                                  
       End If

       Val = GetSingleFromString(Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 3).Value)
       Val2 = GetSingleFromString(Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 3).Offset(0, 1).Value)

       If Val >= 7 And Val2 <= 10 Then
           Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(OutputRow , 2).Value = _
           Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 5).Value             'copy cell  value from E @the current row to column B @the output row
           OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
       End If

    Next x

    'Sort the output:
    Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B:B").Sort key1:=Range(.Cells(StartOutputRow,2), order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlNo
End Sub 

Private Function GetSingleFromString(ByVal InString As String) As Single        

    If Len(InString) <= -1 Then
        GetSingleFromString = -1
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim X As Long
    Dim Temp1 As String
    Dim Output As String

    For X = 1 To Len(InString)
        Temp1 = Mid(InString, X, 1)
        If IsNumeric(Temp1) Or Temp1 = "." Then Output = Output & Temp1
    Next

    If Len(Output) > 0 Then
        GetSingleFromString = CSng(Output)
    Else
        GetSingleFromString = -1
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Your code and function fix the string problem so thank you @peter! I am still learning how to incorporate functions efficiently to a sub. The only problem I have now is that I need the code to find and return the values based on the range in chronological order. Sometimes "8" could fall in a cell before "7", so the loop will find the value corresponding to 8 and copy it first. I need the code to copy 7 first and then move to 8, 9, and 10...Would you know how to rearrange the code to do this? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Not sure I'm grasping your desired function exactly, but I believe what you want is for your output to be sorted in ascending order.  This could be accomplished a handful of different ways - you could add each result to an array, sort the array, and then output the data to a range.  You could use the code as is, and then apply a filter to sort the data after it's all done.  You could use the Range.Sort method to sort data.  There are multiple ways to do this - it really is up to you to decide the design of your program, which I would say is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I see what you're saying..
Basically I want to say: Go down until you find 7, copy value in column D to the other sheet. Next, go down Column B, until you find 8, copy value from Column D in other sheet, etc. This way it sorts the values beforehand because sometimes the range I'm looking for, 7-10, will not occur in numerical order from smallest to largest, Going down B, you could find 8 in "B6", 9 in "B7", 7 in "B8", and 10 in "B9", instead of 7, 8, 9, 10 going down B.

Comment: This is my output based on what I have:
71.6
83.12
76.17
74.69

This is my desired output:
83.12
76.07
76.17
75.99
74.79
74.41
74.51
71.6
If that helps...I greatly appreciate your time

Comment: @Alex664 - why can't you sort that output then after the fact? I'm not saying you can't do what you want - sorting first-  it's just more complicated.  Not sure I see the benefit of doing it before vs after.  If you get the desired output, it's just out of order, than it would make more sense to me to sort it after.  Have you looked into the [Range.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) function I mentioned?

Comment: I have but it is actually more complicated unfortunately, than sorting afterwards. The numbers in Column B will vary in order for different excel sheets and the start and end values want will vary based on the user's preference and what is to be searched

Comment: I updated my answer to include the sort afterwards (I started writing before you posted last comment).  At this point, I would recommend you start a new question regarding the sorting.  You won't get a lot of attention on this question as it already has answers, and you're getting off-topic from the original question, so I think you'll get more help if you post it as a separate question.  Just make sure you explain in details what you are trying to do, what you've attempted, and where you are stuck.

Comment: @Alex664 - if you found my answer helped you, please take the time to mark the checkbox next to my answer to make it green.  Thanks!  I'll look for your second question.

Comment: Got it! Once I figure out the next move I will be sure to post it. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: The last line of code doesn't run when adding a parenthesis at the end...how does this line sort it?

Comment: Where are you adding a parenthese? Look at my comment 4 hours ago with the link to the MSDN for range.sort for an explanation how it sorts.